# How this method is called without using the classname

Tags: java

I wanted to know how a static method is called in another class.

Assume I have a class as following,

```
class classA
{
public static void method1(String a)
{
}
}
```

In another class the method method1 is called as following,

```
class classB
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
 method1("Alpha");
 }
 }
```

Please note that the ClassB is not extending the ClassA, I am confused.

Comment: One more thing, always [indent your code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style)

Answer (score 4):

You can use a static import:

```
import static yourpackage.classA.method1;
```

For more information see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html

If you are working in **default package**, the import will fail, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1964006/2039482

Side note: Class names are conventionally always starting with an upper case letter

Answer (score 1):

If you have in your class B `static import yourpacage.ClassA` you can call static methods without writting the class name.

Answer (score 0):

If the two classes are in the same package you don't have to import them you can simply go:

```
Classname.methodName(possibleParameter);
```

If not in the same package import the package as mentioned by Bernhard Poiss.

Answer (score 0):

i can't see how something like this can happen, unless:

1. classB is a static inner class of classA or something of that sort.
2. you have a static import somewhere (and that works only if you place the classes inside a package).